# Find links to the current post/question elsewhere on the SE network

Tags: support, hyperlinks, linked-questions

*I'd like to locale all places that link* to *the current post or question*: [linked-questions](/questions/tagged/linked-questions) the other way.

It's less important if it produces:

- things that reference a post specifically or anything in the same Q&A
- just posts or posts+comments
- network-wise or just specific sites

Specifically, I'm interested in links to an MSE discussion at SO and MSO.

I've seen such a link recently, thus the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag. It's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/4660142?lq=1 . **So, the questions are:**

- Where is it in the UI?
- Which of the above-mentioned combinations it implements?
- Are there other variations - e.g. implementing other combinations?